# how to convert array of data in to json using jsonkit?

Tags: iphone, ios

I am getting NSString like this

```
 [Hello] [;]
 [hi] [;]
 [Its there] [;]
 [Welcome] [;]
 [Hello] [;]
```

i want to convert as a json format, i don't know how to convert the array of data into json. please help me

Comment: Show us the input string and the code you've written to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the following code.

```
NSDictionary *dict = [myJsonString JSONValue];
```

If it's not working then use following

```
// 
// we begin with our string in json format
//
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"{\"1\":\"1: Rossy Robinson - $25\",\"2\":\"7: Davey Ambrose - $25\",\"3\":\"14: Ross Robinson - $25\"}"];

//
// convert the json string to an NSMutableDictionary
//
NSError *e;
NSMutableDictionary *JSONdic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: [jsonString dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding] options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &e];

//
// change a value and add a new value in the dict
//
NSLog(@"before: object for key 1 is: %@", [JSONdic objectForKey:@"1"]);
[JSONdic setObject:@"xxx" forKey:@"1"];
[JSONdic setObject:@"Phil McQuitty" forKey:@"2"];

//
//convert dictionary object to json data
//
NSData* jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:JSONdic options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&e];

//
// convert the json data back to a string
//
NSString *jsonText = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];\

//
// print out the final results
//
NSLog(@"back to string: %@", jsonText);
```

Comment: this program line is very useful to me

Comment: i am having a data in textile, how i assign to objectkey and how to convert into json format, for store the values into server.

Comment: i am not getting your problem ?

Comment: i am having a data in info.txt, how i assign to objectkey and how i convert into Json format, for store the string values into the server

Comment: for that you need to get the values from the NSBundle then fetch the detail and then you can get the string and then apply jsonkit function

Comment: i am getting NSString format,  i want to convert into dictionary format of json

Comment: For that you apply just above code then you gets the json string and that json string pass to server

Comment: i don't know  how to assign the value into setobject and also object indexkey for bundle of data. please help me